# Block mailer daemon emails for manually blocked email IDs using access map

Tags: linux, email, fedora, sendmail

I have blocked emails to some addresses by using line like

```
To:a@b.com                  ERROR:"550 Mailbox disabled for this recipient"
```

But I am getting lot of messages from "Mail Delivery Subsystem ". How do I disable getting MAILER-DAEMON notifications only for this user? I can do this in my email client but I was hoping for more efficient method to stop server from sending such emails.

I do not want the other mails from "Mail Delivery Subsystem " to be stopped. The error message should not be sent for the addresses which I have manually blocked in access map.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, warren's answer seems to suggest that you dump all messages, but of course you could set up `procmail` to only dump the ones from MAILER-DAEMON which actually refer to `a@b.com`. This is done with something like

```
# Postmaster notifications: Move to doublebounces if refering to a@b.com
:0 H
* ^From: .*MAILER-DAEMON@domain.com
* ^Subject: (Postmaster notify|Returned mail): .*
{ :0 B
  * a@b.com
  doublebounces
}
```

Your questions does not clearly state which type of bounces you get. I assume it is so-called double bounces. You might want to have a look at a more sophisticaed solution which I posted at [Sysadmin'ish Blog: Selective Sendmail Postmaster](http://www.fam.tuwien.ac.at/~schamane/_/blog:080927_selective_sendmail_postmaster)

Note: Above `procmail` recipes are meant for large servers and try to minimize the load. The 2 recipes could be converted to 1, however slightly more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a `procmail` recipe to just dump the messages to `/dev/null` from that address/domain.